# If $4a^2+9b^2-c^2+12ab=0$,the family of straight lines ax+by+c=0 is concurrent at which point?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quadratics

> If $4a^2+9b^2-c^2+12ab=0$,the family of straight lines $ax+by+c=0$ is
>   concurrent at which point?

How to solve such problems.Hints please!

Comment: $$4a^2+9b^2+12ab-c^2 = (2a)^2 + (3b)^2 + 2 \cdot (2a) \cdot (3b) -c^2 = (2a+3b)^2 - c^2$$

Comment: @gt6989b please explain what you did!

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

What you try to do is complete the square to simplify the expression. Recall that $$(x+z)^2 = x^2 + 2xz + z^2$$
and try to model the first terms in the expression after the pattern on the RHS. We have just fromm those terms:
$$
4a^2+9b^2 + 12ab = (2a)^2 + (3b)^2 + 2 \cdot(2a) \cdot (3b) = (2a+3b)^2.
$$

Therefore,
$$
4a^2+9b^2 + 12ab -c^2 = 0 \text{ implies } (2a+3b)^2-c^2 = 0,
$$
and we have $$c^2 = (2a+3b)^2.$$

Comment: Actually i had found a similar question few days ago except that the equation given was $6a^{2}-3b^{2}-c^{2}+7ab-ac+4bc=0$ how do i complete the square in such cases . (PS : too lazy to post another question)